# storing tree element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, data-structures

I have developed a tree menu using jQuery api. But all my tree elements are hard coded. I want to store the tree elements in a data structure and create the tree dynamically. Does jQuery has any data structure like linked list or sth or do I have to code my own data structure ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use javascript methods, don't forget, that jQuery is just a JS extension.

Here are manuals on javascript data structures:

- http://www.datajett.com/Tuts/JScriptGen/javascriptDataStructs.pdf
- http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter4.html

  var cat = {colour: "grey", name: "Spot", size: 46};
  cat.size = 47;
  show(cat.size);
  delete cat.size;
  show(cat.size);
  show(cat);

Answer (score 1):

See:

- U[se jQuery's data() method to store data in the DOM](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-store-data-in-dom/)